# WPF Command not Enabling a button as expected

Tags: c#, wpf

I have simulated the scenario with a simple example where window has one textbox and a buton beside it. The button gets activated after the value on textbox goes above 10000. But the button is not getting enabled.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="150" Width="225">
<Grid>
    <WrapPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding X}" Width="100"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Width="100"/>
    </WrapPanel>
</Grid>
```

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = vm;
    }

    protected override void OnContentRendered(EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Run(new Action(() =>
        {
            int c = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                vm.X = c++;
            }
        }));

        base.OnContentRendered(e);
    }
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int x;
    public int X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set
        {
            if (x != value)
            {
                x = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("X"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ICommand c = new MyCommand();
    public ICommand ButtonCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return c;
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
public class MyCommand : ICommand
{
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (parameter != null && (parameter as ViewModel).X > 10000)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }

        remove
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your XAML

Comment: make sure to provide parameter that not equal to null
you can put break point to debug if the program get into the if statement to enable the icommand execution

Comment: Yes I have checked and this is never null.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the following...

```
while (true)
{
     vm.X = c++;
     CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to raise the event  CanExecuteChanged at any point you expect  the CanExecute method
output will be changed

so for example you can add

```
CanExecuteChanged ();
     vm.X = c++;
```

Comment: This is not helping!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to implement the ICommand

```
public class MyCommand : ICommand
{
  private bool _CanExecute = true;
  public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
  {

    return _CanExecute;
  }

  public void Execute(object parameter)
  {
    if(parameter!=null){
      _CanExecute = false;
          //do your thing here....
     _CanExecute = true; 
   }
}
```

Purists won't like this pattern but... who cares about all the non-sense of hooking up an tearing down event handlers?  Bottom line is the command can be executed or not regardless of re-query suggested.

Comment: Hi, I want a solution to my problem and this will not fix the problem.

Comment: I want to stick to the model above as it is followed all over the app.